# How can I temporarily disable DependencyProperty constraints when changing DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've built a WPF UserControl which is a slider that permits selecting a range of values. It has four properties for the limits with the constraint

```
MinValue <= RangeMinValue <= RangeMaxValue <= MaxValue
```

On the basis of YAGNI I currently have `MinValue` forced to `0`, and the other three use dependency properties with a `PropertyChangedCallback` to enforce the constraints:

```csharp
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MaxValue), typeof(int), typeof(RangeTrack),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, _EnforceConstraints));

    public int MaxValue { get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); } set { SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value); } }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeMinValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(RangeMinValue), typeof(int), typeof(RangeTrack),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, _EnforceConstraints));

    public int RangeMinValue { get { return (int)GetValue(RangeMinValueProperty); } set { SetValue(RangeMinValueProperty, value); } }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeMaxValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(RangeMaxValue), typeof(int), typeof(RangeTrack),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, _EnforceConstraints));

    public int RangeMaxValue { get { return (int)GetValue(RangeMaxValueProperty); } set { SetValue(RangeMaxValueProperty, value); } }

    // Enforce the constraints MinValue <= RangeMinValue <= RangeMaxValue <= MaxValue
    private static void _EnforceConstraints(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var track = (RangeTrack)d;
        var newValue = (int)e.NewValue;

        // We work on the basis that property changes will cascade, so if the constraints
        // are violated we make one change which will cascade to tidy up the rest.

        if (e.Property == MaxValueProperty)
        {
            // This should be the only test which doesn't involve adjacent values.
            if (newValue < track.MinValue) { track.MaxValue = track.MinValue; return; }
            if (newValue < track.RangeMaxValue) { track.RangeMaxValue = newValue; return; }
        }

        if (e.Property == RangeMaxValueProperty)
        {
            if (newValue > track.MaxValue) { track.RangeMaxValue = track.MaxValue; return; }
            if (newValue < track.RangeMinValue) { track.RangeMinValue = newValue; return; }
        }

        if (e.Property == RangeMinValueProperty)
        {
            if (newValue < track.MinValue) { track.RangeMinValue = track.MinValue; return; }
            if (newValue > track.RangeMaxValue) { track.RangeMaxValue = newValue; return; }
        }
    }
```

The control works perfectly in isolation, but there's a problem with "real life" usage:

```xaml
    <my:RangeSlider MaxValue="{Binding NumFoos}"
                    RangeMinValue="{Binding StartFoo}"
                    RangeMaxValue="{Binding EndFoo}" />
```

When the (inherited) `DataContext` changes, the bindings update, but not simultaneously. Result: the `_EnforceConstraints` callback will be called at a point where some of the values are obtained from binding against the old `DataContext` and some from the new `DataContext`, resulting in undesired changes.

Both `DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata` and the `FrameworkElement.DataContextChanged` event fire before the bindings update, so in principle I could disable the constraints, but I'm not sure on what condition I could safely re-enable them.

#### Rejected attempts at a workaround

I'm willing to assume that the initial bound values of the `DataContext`s used will respect the constraints, and if a context is bound which doesn't then I don't mind the constraints changing its values to be consistent with itself. But even with those assumptions, I haven't found a satisfactory workaround.

1. I think the order of the properties in the XAML affects the order in which they're updated. But whatever order I put them in, there's a potential problem. If `MaxValue` updates first then the constraints can change `RangeMaxValue` on the old `DataContext`; if `RangeMaxValue` updates first then the constraints can clip it to the old context's `MaxValue`, changing the new `DataContext`.
2. I could remove the constraints entirely from the control and enforce them in the `DataContext`. This works, but in my opinion the logically correct place for the constraints is in the control.
3. I could remove the direct enforcement from the callback and instead apply the constraints in `ArrangeOverride` (since all of the `DependencyProperties` have `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange`). The control isn't rearranged until all of the properties have changed, so in principle this should work (although it means tracking some extra state to see whether the violation of `RangeMinValue <= RangeMaxValue` is because the min value was increased or the max value was decreased), but it feels very hacky.
4. Use `CoerceValueCallback`s in conjunction with `PropertyChangedCallback`s to trigger manual re-coercion.

   ```
   private static void _MaxValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs evt)
   {
       // Cascade: MaxValue directly impacts on RangeMaxValue, which directly impacts on RangeMinValue, so they must be coerced in that order.
       d.CoerceValue(RangeMaxValueProperty);
       d.CoerceValue(RangeMinValueProperty);
   }

   private static object _CoerceMaxValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
   {
       var track = (RangeTrack)d;
       ValueType value = (ValueType)baseValue;

       if (value < track.MinValue) value = track.MinValue;
       return value;
   }

   private static void _RangeMaxValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs evt)
   {
       d.CoerceValue(RangeMinValueProperty);
   }

   private static object _CoerceRangeMaxValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
   {
       var track = (RangeTrack)d;
       ValueType value = (ValueType)baseValue;

       // NB We might have track.RangeMinValue > track.MaxValue at certain points in the coercion cascade.
       if (value < track.RangeMinValue) value = track.RangeMinValue;
       if (value > track.MaxValue) value = track.MaxValue;
       return value;
   }

   private static void _RangeMinValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs evt)
   {
       d.CoerceValue(RangeMaxValueProperty);
   }

   private static object _CoerceRangeMinValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
   {
       var track = (RangeTrack)d;
       ValueType value = (ValueType)baseValue;

       if (value > track.RangeMaxValue) value = track.RangeMaxValue;
       if (value < track.MinValue) value = track.MinValue;
       return value;
   }
   ```

   The problem here is that if I try to "push" the thumb for `RangeMaxValue` by dragging the thumb for `RangeMinValue`, neither moves, but if I then move the `RangeMaxValue` thumb then the `RangeMinValue` jumps to catch up with it.

Is workaround 3 the best option going, or is there something I've missed?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3024312/573420)

Comment: You may probably better use a [`CoerceValueCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `PropertyChangedCallback`.

Comment: @Clemens, but if `MaxValue` changes then the `PropertyChangedCallback` might need to update `RangeMaxValue` to respect the constraint, and a `CoerceValueCallback` won't do that.